# How can I patch a node via REST in different languages?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm using the REST API to get my Drupal content into an app. This app has to be translated to at least 8 different languages, so we are using [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com) as a translation service. I wrote a small module that automatically sends the title and subtitle of a node to [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com) for translation and I'm working on sending it back, when my file was translated.

Now to the problem:

How can I patch a node to add a title for a different language than the default one? Or do I have to post it again? When translating it in Drupal directly I get two nodes with the same ID and different language codes.

But how do I do it via REST?

Creating a node is no problem, patching a node is also no problem but I don't know how to patch it for a different language than the default one.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: By passing language parameter in request & on basis of that getting result?